Multiple Users Simultaneously Press Button, Makes Infinite Loop Ineffective on C#
I have a c# infinite loop code on a WinForm project, which uses a value in SQL which alternates between 1/0 and if it's 0 it'll continue the process, while if it's 1 it'll stay in the loop. The purpose of this code is to prevent more than one person processing X.
My problem is that if I have multiple users using the program, and some of them press the button to run the process at the same time, the loop doesn't manage to catch that there's already someone processing X.
I figure the problem is that all users are reading the SQL value before any one of them has a chance to update the value in SQL to 1, and prevent other users from proceeding with the process.
Is there a way to fix this?
Here's a sample code of the loop:
SqlDataReader VerifyIfBusyReader = null;
                
                SqlCommand VerifyIfBusy = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Value] FROM [Variables] WHERE [TYPE] = 'IsBusy'", CONNECTION);
                int verify = 1;
                int counts = 0;
                int milliseconds = 2000;
                while (verify == 1)
                {
                    counts++;
                    if (counts == 30)
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    VerifyIfBusyReader = VerifyIfBusy.ExecuteReader();
                    VerifyIfBusyReader.Read();
                    if (int.Parse(VerifyIfBusyReader[0].ToString()) == 1)
                    {
                        VerifyIfBusyReader.Close();
                    }
                    else if (int.Parse(VerifyIfBusyReader[0].ToString()) == 0)
                    {
                        verify = 0;
                        VerifyIfBusyReader.Close();
                    }
                    
                    Thread.Sleep(milliseconds);
                }

                SqlCommand IsBusyNow = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [Variables] SET [VALUE] = 1 WHERE [TYPE] = 'IsBusy'", CONNECTION);
                VerifyIfBusyReader = IsBusyNow.ExecuteReader();
                VerifyIfBusyReader.Close();

Any help is appreciated.
Of course, I have another function that updates SQL back to 0 once it finishes, but that's not the issue here.

Why not use an advisory lock? See sp_getapplock / sp_releaseapplock

Can't use something I don't know about... I'll look into it. Any other alternatives?

@canton7 For sp_getapplock you need to hold open the connection, which isn't always advised.

You have a race condition in between getting a not-busy result and setting it.
You can instead use an UPDATE with an OUTPUT, which will be atomic. Just loop it until you get a result.
Note that if you are not supposed to get a resultset then you should use ExecuteNonQuery, and for a single result you can use ExecuteScalar.

Use async where possible
Make sure to dispose with using.
You don't need to store the result and loop, you can break the loop immediately.
Use proper for looping, rather than while.

using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnStringHere))
{
    using SqlCommand SetBusyOrNull = new SqlCommand(@"
UPDATE Variables
SET VALUE = 1
OUTPUT inserted.VALUE
WHERE TYPE = 'IsBusy'
  AND VALUE = 0;
", conn);

    int counts = 30;
    int milliseconds = 2000;
    for (var i = 0; i < counts; i++)
    {
        conn.Open();
        var isSet = (SetBusyOrNull.ExecuteScalar()) as int? == 1;
        conn.Close();
        if (isSet)
            return true;

        Thread.Sleep(milliseconds);
    }
    throw new Exception($"Still busy after {counts} tries");
    // alternatively return false;
}


I'll test this as soon as I can, this seems more in-line with what I was looking for. And thanks for the tip on ExecuteNonQuery, I'm mostly modifying projects from a previous programmer and I've self-taught myself C# enough to make things work, but still very much a noob. Thanks. I'll let you know when I can test this.
Any particular reason we want to use async within this particular loop?

So as not to block the UI. In WinForms the top level event handler should be declared as async void and all functions below that as async Task.

For this situation I kinda prefer for it to lock the UI, this program is not really tempered for an active UI while it is doing other processes and I rather not have to go through the full project to make that adjustment. It's a project I didn't write myself, only modifying it so don't want to touch it too much.

I'm confused on when isSet becomes true. I don't think it's working, as in it's looping for 2 minutes. I changed the return true; to a break;, but that shouldn't affect it. When I pause the code, it keeps saying iSet is false, I added a breakpoint to to confirm that the column get updated from 0 to 1 before the if (isSet) line.
Just in case, I'm  opening and closing the connection outside of the loop in case closing the connection is needed prior to the isSet check.

OK, after some troubleshooting the issue mentioned above could have been because the database has a compatibility level for SQL 2000, so I moved this procedure to another database and it's now giving me isSet true, so at least I fixed that part. Now have to do more tests, but I think this will solve my problems. Will update later.

Preliminary testing looks like this solution is working, thank you very much. I'm marking this as the answer.

You might be casting to the wrong type. What is the exact type of the column? Note that SQL Server 2008 is now way out of support, and running on a compatibility level for a 24 year old product seems insane.

It's working once I moved to an appropriate compatibility level. I work on a small business running GP Dynamics, and upgrading it is incredibly expensive for no real added benefit for what we do. And GP Dynamics is very strict on what SQL version it can run on or from where it can upgrade if I ever decide to do so. So no real reason to throw money at it.

No reason to throw money at it? The security vulnerabilities alone are all the reason to throw money at it.
